# Issue with items of listview

Tags: java, android, listview

i don't know why but when i add items to listview i get only the last item. E.G. if i write apple and than pear i get only pear and not apple and pear.
Why?

[image]

CODE:

```
 holder.button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                System.out.println("IDDD:"+iddd);
                System.out.println("IDDD:"+video2.getPic());

                //holder.lw.setA

                String commento= (holder.tw.getText().toString());
               // holder.lw.setAdapter(adapter);
                 ArrayList<String> arrayList= new ArrayList<String>();
                final ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(context, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, arrayList);
                arrayList.add(commento);
                // next thing you have to do is check if your adapter has changed
                holder.lw.setAdapter(adapter);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                System.out.println("LISTVIEW:"+arrayList);


            }

        });
```

Comment: The reason your code isn't working is because you are always creating a new ArrayList containing only one item, and you are also creating a new Adapter and setting it on the ListView. So no matter what, your code will only show the very last comment. Also the notifyDataSetChanged is redundant because in the line before setAdapter will functionally do the same thing.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please try to clean your code to only include relevant parts (remove commented code, debug outputs and so on) to make it easier for others to locate cricitcal parts. See also [minimal code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in every click you decalre new list `ArrayList<String> arrayList= new ArrayList<String>();` and it's false

you need to declate it out of the listener and in your listener just add the new items and use adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

Comment: ok, now array list have both items but i see only the last in listview...why?

Comment: try to toast adapter.getitemCount() to see if the adapter has only one value or has all values , and tell me what the result

Answer (score 1):

You are creating new list and adapter during every click so move the declaration and initialization of both, outside that function

- Declare them outside `getView`(if Base or ArrayAdaoter) or `createViewHolder` (RecyclerAdapter)
- initialize them inside `constructor`
- add data to list and notify adapter

Answer (score 0):

Better use view holder pattern in here where you use Existing instance of listview rather than recreating the new one all the time.

Comment: `final ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(contex` mean, won't work

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do anything special, inside of onClick you need to get a reference to your ArrayAdapter and call the method add(T...) on it.

```
holder.button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                System.out.println("IDDD:"+iddd);
                System.out.println("IDDD:"+video2.getPic());


                String commento= (holder.tw.getText().toString());
                ArrayAdapter adapter = (ArrayAdapter) holder.lw.getAdapter();
                adapter.add(commento);    
            }    
        });
```

No need to even call notifyDataSetChanged because add already does that internally.

Answer (score -1):

if you use this you can solve your problem

```
yourAdapter.(getCount()-1-position);
```

and this if you want to see the last items in front

```
  public yourPoJo getItem(int position) {
                return super.getItem(getCount()-1-position);
            }
```